# Styling drop down list for in MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, model, html.dropdownlistfor

Hi I am trying to style my drop down list using some css and javascript. The only difficulty that I am facing is that I am using models with MVC and tools are different so I am not using select tags.

at the moment this is how I am showing and populating my drop down list for

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.teamIdAway, Model.getTeams, new { style = "width: 135px" })%>
```

and populating this from the model

Can anyone tell me some basic code or what can I do to style my drop down list

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code - what HtmlHelper method are you using to display / render the dropdown? What kind of styling do you want to do? Add a class? Add a style attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` renders a `<select>`, so I don't know why you're saying you're not using `<select>` tags.

CSS does not care about server-side code, only rendered HTML, so if you're having issues then always show us the rendered HTML and your CSS.

Anyway, to style your `<select>` element (and remember that because `<select>` is a "replaced element" in CSS the opportunities for styling are limited, but you can do some cool things: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

You can override the `id=""` attribute of the `<select>` so you can use the element selector in CSS, like so:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.teamIdAway, Model.getTeams, new { id = "mySelect" })%>

#mySelect { width: 135px; }
```

However if you're using this `DropDownListFor` in a partial view then the `id=""` attribute won't be unique in the document, which is illegal. Try using different selectors that make use of the context, such as the descendant selector.